# Is there a way I could somehow do some sort of nested import statement?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

So in python you can do `from foo import bar`, this gets the bar from foo but how can I get something from inside of the bar object

I.e

```py
from foo import bar.childDef  # gets childDef() from inside of bar
```

Because normally you would have to type `bar.childDef()` with a regular import statement using from,
however I just wanna use `childDef()` instead of `bar.childDef()`

Sorry if this is a confusing or just bad question in general, I'm just curious.

Comment: What are `bar` and `childDef`? Are they modules, or some other flavor of namespaces?

Comment: I assume `bar` is a class and `childDef` is a method? In that case, I don't think it's possible. If it is a function, just do `from bar import childDef`

Comment: nevermind i found another way to do it. just create a method that locally imports bar, then returns bar.childDef(), now you can call the class and it will be the same as calling bar.childDef() whilst also not importing extra stuff, so it works just like how a nested import would if it actually existed in python lol

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

```py
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now
```

or

```py
def now():
  import datetime
  return datetime.datetime.now()
now()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
## foo.py

class bar:
  def childDef ():
    print('Child Def')
```

And import from another script,

```
from foo import bar
# import method
imported_fun = bar.childDef
#call method
bar.childDef() # or  imported_fun()
```